# Android Studio and GitHub organization integration

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I have an account in a GitHub organization (paid account). I want to share my Android project into a **private** GitHub repository, but when I try to push the files I get an error from Android Studio. It looks like I cannot save in a private repository because I must upgrade my plan... but my plan is already a paid plan with other private repositories. Why is Android Studio not able to share my project in a private repository ?

Comment: Can you push without using AS?

Comment: Yes I can. I can also sign in from Android Studio with my GitHub user, but when I share the project and I check the PRIVATE checkbox I get the error. It looks like AS is no able to recognize I'm using a paid GitHub account. If I share it in a public repository (free account) it works.